# Function for putting together a series

Tags: series-expansion

For instance Series[Exp[x],...] gives you expansion of Exp[x].
But how would I obtain Exp[x] if I give a summation function?

Comment: `Sum[x^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}]`?

Comment: Thanks. Exactly! appreciate it!!!